# opencv 3.2.0 can not acces camera 0

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

Compiled opencv 3.2.0 to mingw - codeblocks in windows 10 creators

i can write programs in opencv, they run, e.g. Lena.cpp.
but when i need the camera, the program run, making the window but it doesn't show the camera(0) of the laptop.
Here's the code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
VideoCapture stream1(0);   //0 is the id of video device.0 if you have only one camera.

if (!stream1.isOpened()) { //check if video device has been initialised
    cout << "cannot open camera";
}

//unconditional loop
while (true) {
    Mat cameraFrame;
    stream1.read(cameraFrame);
    imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the camera is not being used by another program?

Comment: yes, camera is free.

Comment: Try this sample code - http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

Comment: @JackGold the same error occurs

Comment: i need to kill the process to exit, "edges (not responding)"

Comment: The `if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;` line of code should ensure that the program does not exit. Have you tried debugging your code? at what point does it stop working?

Comment: with waitkey, the program autocloses inmediately, at least, without waitkey my program stays in an eternal loop, but camera should work, but not

Comment: Note: Even if the camera is being used by another app, stream1.isOpened() will return true

Comment: Your code looks fine, should work. I can start capturing frames from the default camera using OpenCV with similar code.

Comment: Do you see `cannot open camera` logged in the console? or you see a window with black background ?

Comment: - @ZdaR, window have a dark gray background

Comment: Then there may be some issue with your camera drivers.

Comment: yes, i'll downgrade opencv, also try with win10 ubuntu bash..... 
it may be caused by win10 creators update, or camera drive, or some error in c-make

Comment: WORKS OPENCV IN WIN10-CREATORS UPDATE?
some code examples of opencv doesn't work here.....
all example codes still running in background
i need taskmgr to kill them
i repeat: IS THE OPENCV EXAMPLE C++ CODES